# How to create a div which occupies space with its position fixed?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div(located at the top) which has its own space and also its position is fixed. The requirement is when it is scrolled down, it has to move and on scrolling up it should go back to its own space.

When position is fixed it is moving up and down. But it loses the space for it. How to achieve the space for it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code (HTML, CSS) of what you have tried, preferably as a snippet or jsFiddle

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of navbar that's at the top of the page, but then as you scroll down it sticks to the top of the viewport? A JSFiddle would help, too.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are wanting something like **affix**.  Check out http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix as an example.

Comment: I think you mean "sticky" positioning. CSS support for that is new and not implemented by all browsers yet. Here is [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning).

For now it is best to use a javascript library. @jusopi made a good suggestion to use bootstrap's affix feature which emulates sticky positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/danhaswings/a1zb6ye9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore itaque doloremque delectus incidunt deleniti, excepturi, saepe nesciunt asperiores quae repellendus quisquam consequatur. Vero tenetur saepe eos ipsum harum culpa velit alias blanditiis maiores libero voluptates autem nostrum dolorem dolorum, beatae ullam. Explicabo tenetur necessitatibus modi illum alias! Eius enim accusantium, totam quibusdam fuga aliquam quod numquam. Consequuntur et ipsum earum voluptatum iure soluta necessitatibus minima unde nesciunt repellendus excepturi quod, exercitationem voluptates. Veniam temporibus aliquam amet maxime ex, voluptatibus ipsum consequatur quibusdam laborum, itaque reprehenderit. Optio dignissimos, maiores, debitis accusamus itaque corporis laboriosam nisi fuga! Quas porro eos qui, numquam.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    min-height: 2000px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.navbar {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```